# Xcode 8 - Can't find User Header Paths

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode8

I have a project that was previously running in XCode 7, under Swift 2.2. However, I started migrating it to Xcode 8 and Swift 2.3 (Swift 3 will come later). This is my first time migrating a project, so I'm fairly new to a lot of concepts.

I keep getting the following error: 
    'JBBarChartView.h'file not found.

This is how my project looks like (blurred out the unimportant parts for privacy reasons)

[image]

The blue arrow points to the Bridging Header.
This is what my bridging header looks like: [image]

and this here is my actual folder structure. [image]

The important Header Files, such as the JBBarChartView.h, are inside the Vendor Folder. For some odd reason, Xcode simply cannot find the files, and thus fails to import the Bridging Header.

**So far what I have tried is:**

- For the related Target, I have set **Swift Compiler - General > Objective-C Bridging Header** to the correct location.
- I have set the Header Search Paths for the Target to **../../${SRCROOT}** and recursive.
- I have also selected **YES** on **Always search user paths**
- And my User Header Search Paths are also: **../../${SRCROOT}** and recursive. (manually, in my build settings)
- I also have an xconfig file which looks like this: HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "../$(SRCROOT)/**" (among other, but they are all separated by a blank space.)
- I have too cleaned the DerivedData Folder, and restarted Xcode several times.

No matter what I try, for some odd reason Xcode can't find those headers. Does anybody have an idea what I could try?

Answer (score 0):

This `../../${SRCROOT}` looks wrong - Very possibly you want `${SRCROOT}/../Vendor/` (or something close).

When you add that, it *should* expand the SRCROOT macro and show you the actual path being generated... Does that look correct?

For example, when I use:

```
${SRCROOT}/../Vendor/
```

I get:

```
/Users/DonMag/Source/TestProj/../Vendor/
```

Which would put my Vendor files that I'm looking for in:

```
/Users/DonMag/Source/Vendor/
```

---

My Steps to Resolve This:

Create a new `FindMe.h` file in your project. Put `#define FOUNDIT 1` in it. Add `#include "FindMe.h"` to the top of `AppDelegate.m`.

Add to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
#ifdef FOUNDIT
    NSLog(@"Woo Hoo");
#endif
```

Naturally, that should compile and run without issue.

Next, delete the reference to FindMe.h from your project, and move FindMe.h up one folder level. Try to compile --- and you should get a "FindMe.h not found" error.

Add `${SRCROOT}` as a `Header Search Path`

Try to compile / run. That ***should*** work. If so...

Move FindMe.h up another folder level, and change `Header Search Path` to `${SRCROOT}/../`. Compile/run --- should work.

Keep following that process - move `.h` one level (up or down into a new folder), edit your `Header Search Path`, build/run to confirm... until you've reached the target folder of your "Vendor" header files.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested, using     ${SRCROOT}/../Vendor/ and the path looks correct, too. But for some odd reason, Xcode still isn't able to find those files. Do you have any other idea what might be causing this problem?

Comment: Or, is there atleast a way to see where Xcode is searching for in the build log?

Comment: I edited my answer with the steps I would take to figure out what's not-quite-right.

Comment: I'm trying out your solution right now - where should i delete the reference from the FindMe.h ? in xcode directly or in the project folder?

Comment: ok so my problem is, no matter what I do, I never even get to the error that I could get when FindMe.h is missing, because the other error, 'JBBarChartViewController.h is missing' always blocks my build after that.

Comment: Assuming you used File -> New -> File... and selected "Header File" from within Xcode, FindMe.h will be listed in the Project Navigator pane. Delete it from there, but select Remove Reference (*not* Move to Trash). Now move the file around in a normal Finder window.

Comment: Ah, sorry... I meant start a new Project, so you can figure out the Header Search Path independently. If your current project is at `/Users/Misha/Projects/MyProj/` then create a new project at `/Users/Misha/Projects/TempProj/` -- if you can get the search path correct from TempProj, it should be easy to resolve it in MyProj

Comment: alright, I tried out your suggestion - Everything works fine, for the TempProject I created. BUT - as soon as I change to my real project again, and input the same (obviously correct) path, I keep getting the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: Could there be some issue with the xconfig file? or anything else? I'm really desperate because I have to get this project to work haha;;

Comment: Hard to say... it looks like you've got a lot going on there - I don't use Pods myself (in large part because of integration issues). Maybe try creating another new project and going through the process of adding the JBChart stuff to the new project. If that is successful, try to compare settings and Bridging header, and just look for something that doesn't quite match up.